# WARNING: The advertisement key 'Service Data' is not allowed

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am developing a BLE peripheral app. By requirement, the advertising packet must contain Service Data field. I have done this in Android, the packet should be like this:

[image]

0x16 is Service Data field listed here https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile/

Same thing, I do it in iOS. I use BluetoothCore framework to implement the bluetooth peripheral.

Below is the attribute I should use to set value for Service Data field:

```
advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey] = <somedata>
```

However I got a warning:

> WARNING: The advertisement key 'Service Data' is not allowed

Can someone let me know why and what is the solution?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot specify service data when advertising a peripheral on iOS. You can only specify the service UUID and the service name.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393252-startadvertising):

> **`advertisementData`**
>
> An optional dictionary containing the data you want to advertise. The possible keys of an advertisementData dictionary are detailed in `CBCentralManagerDelegate`. That said, only two of the keys are supported for peripheral manager objects: `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey` and `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey`.

The solution to your warning is to remove `CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey` from the advertising data dictionary.

I'm afraid there isn't a solution to your requirements on iOS.

Comment: Do you know why Apple has that policy?

Comment: No. My guess would be they just didn’t see a need for it when they implemented Core BlueTooth. There may also be reasons of battery efficiency etc.

Comment: this is able to do in Android, I also have no idea why CoreBluetooth doesn't allow us to do.

Comment: I don't know either, but you can't.  Sorry.