# How to set an advertisement payload and a scan response payload on an iOS Peripheral using CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I've implemented similar functionality on **Android** using and it works cleanly and I'm able to grab the advertisement payload & scan response payload with this API defined in `android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseData` package.

```java
AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .setIncludeDeviceName(false)
            .addServiceUuid(uuid)
            .addServiceData(uuid, data)
```

and I'm able to use this to get scan response payload and advertisement payload cleanly and reliably if I start advertising *like this* assuming `advtData` & `scanRespData` payloads are defined using the above code snippet

```java
obj.startAdvertising(advCfg, advtData,scanRespData, advtCallback)
```

with this I'm able to clearly express and advertise an Android peripheral while also exposing the advertisement payload and the scan response payload separately and with their respective UUIDs.

I was looking to get the same done in iOS & I've looked into the following and I don't have a working solution yet.

- **peripheralManager.startAdvertising(...)**: here I can only set the Device Local name, the advertising does happen but the scan response payload and advertisement payload are null on Android; I was expecting that iOS would have certain builder APIs that would expose some meaningful information on scan response and advertisement payload, but this is clearly not the one
- **exposing a read-only characteristic against a service UUID**: while this would help expose the data payload, it wouldn't be visible until the connection has been established and it isn't what I'd like for my peripheral
- setting overflow key in peripheralManager.startAdvertising 's dictionary; this results in a warning and this isn't an error; the advertising happens, but no relevant payload is exposed & if I set the key to a hashmap of `CBUUID:NSData` I get an IllegalArgumentException;
- setting deviceLocalName key: a local name key looks like a good middle ground but I'd prefer a different scan

Let me know if I'm missing something or this is something Apple's CoreBluetooth lacks this feature altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advertising service data is currently impossible on iOS, see this discussion:
[WARNING: The advertisement key 'Service Data' is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56315371/warning-the-advertisement-key-service-data-is-not-allowed)

Despite Apple has documentation for [CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbadvertisementdataservicedatakey), it's not supported in [startAdvertising](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393252-startadvertising) method.